# Angularjs ng-model Returned Undefined When Passing Parameter to a Function in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use `ng-model` in a struts2 textfield and try to pass the value to a function in angularjs controller. It returns with undefined value. What is wrong?

In below code I tried to pass `ng-model="orderDetail.idProduct"` value to my `$scope.idProductNgBlur` function. The value is always found undefined by the function. Does the `ng-repeat` contribute to this error?

Below is the function

```
$scope.idProductNgBlur = function (){
    console.log("The $scope.orderDetail.idProduct : " + $scope.orderDetail.idProduct);
}
```

And in the HTML I had this:

```html
<div class="row" ng-repeat="orderDetail in orderDetails">
    <!-- <s:submit cssClass="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeNewOrderDetail('{{orderDetail.id}}')" value="Remove Order Detail" /> -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <s:textfield type="text" ng-if="orderDetail.idOrderDetail" ng-model="orderDetail.idOrderDetail" name="orderDetails[{{$index}}].idOrderDetail" id="orderDetails[{{$index}}].idOrderDetail" placeholder="Id Order Detail" value="{{orderDetail.idOrderDetail}}" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <s:textfield type="text" ng-if="orderDetail.idOrderDetail" ng-model="orderDetail.idProduct" name="orderDetails[{{$index}}].idProduct" id="orderDetails[{{$index}}].idProduct" placeholder="Id Product" value="{{orderDetail.idProduct}}" ng-blur="idProductNgBlur()"/></div> 
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <s:textfield type="text" ng-if="orderDetail.idOrderDetail" ng-model="orderDetail.amount" name="orderDetails[{{$index}}].amount" id="orderDetails[{{$index}}].amount" placeholder="Amount" value="{{orderDetail.amount}}" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <s:textfield type="text" ng-if="orderDetail.idOrderDetail" ng-model="orderDetail.unitPrice" name="orderDetails[{{$index}}].unitPrice" id="orderDetails[{{$index}}].unitPrice" placeholder="Unit Price" value="{{orderDetail.unitPrice}}" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <s:textfield type="text" ng-if="orderDetail.idOrderDetail" ng-model="orderDetail.subTotal" name="orderDetails[{{$index}}].subTotal" id="orderDetails[{{$index}}].subTotal" placeholder="Sub Total" value="{{orderDetail.subTotal}}" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing it you are calling it.

Passing would be something like:

```
$scope.idProductNgBlur = function (id){
    console.log("The $scope.orderDetail.idProduct : " + id);
}
```

And in HTML on the line where you are calling ng-blur pass, your orderDetail.idProduct:

```
<s:textfield type="text" ng-if="orderDetail.idOrderDetail" ng-model="orderDetail.idProduct" name="orderDetails[{{$index}}].idProduct" id="orderDetails[{{$index}}].idProduct" placeholder="Id Product" value="{{orderDetail.idProduct}}" ng-blur="idProductNgBlur(orderDetail.idProduct)"/></div>
```

Comment: Great answer. I solved my problem with your answer. Thanks a lot Sehax.